# What is the meaning of 0x800a1421 HRESULT?

Tags: c++, com, ole

I have a dll written in C++. It's main purpouse is to call methods on Word by OLE. I try to call a method "SaveAs":

```
HRESULT hr;
szFunction = OLESTR("SaveAs");
    hr = doc->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &szFunction, 1, 
            LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 
            &dispid_Cap);
    hr = doc->Invoke(dispid_Cap, IID_NULL, 
            LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, 
            &dpCap, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

It fails and I can't figure out why. The value of hr is -2146823135. 
I converted it to hex like this:

```
sprintf(hex_buff, "%x", (unsigned int)hr);
```

which gave **0x800a1421**

I tried to find out what this code means with this program: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=985
But the result was:

```
as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), Facility: 0xa, Code 0x1421
NOT FOUND: 800a1421
```

What does it mean? How should I proceed to find out why my method fails?

Comment: Try to take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT

Comment: I did, but all I have find out is that '8' stands for failure (moreover), '0xa' points me to facility 'Control', and the error code is 0x1421. Still, I can't figure out what 0x1421 means...

Comment: Please change the question from "...of this HRESULT?" to "...of 0x800a1421 HRESULT"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A big reason you are having trouble diagnosing the error is because you took one shortcut too many.  You are passing NULL for the IDispatch::Invoke()'s *pExcepInfo* argument.  Which is okay with IDispatch, it basically means "don't bother telling me what you know about the exception, I'll sort it out myself from the error code".  You'll miss out on goodies like the textual description of the error and the help file that documents it.  If available.  Clearly you don't want to take this kind of shortcut when you ask this question.

Anyhoo, you can still reverse-engineer the problem from the exception code.  Facility 0x0a are reserved for OLE Automation apps, the error code is specific to the app.  Which turns 0x1421 in "Word error 5153".  Put that in a Google query, the second hit gives you a link to somebody that has figured out what error 5153 means.

You are trying to overwrite a file that somebody else has opened.  Very common mishap.

Fix your code, you'll want to show the error description to a human so they can take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

Info about `0x800a1421` from '**HR Plus**' tool:

- Error Type: OLE HRESULT
- Error Facility: FACILITY_CONTROL `0x0000000A`
- Severity: SEVERITY_ERROR `0x00000001`
- Code: `0x00001421`

And about `0x00001421` from '**Error Lookup**' tool:
***Control ID not found*.**